# AWS Beanstalk - running shell script where command does not execute successfully

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ec2-ami

I'm running an app on AWS beanstalk and troubleshooting an issue I'm having.  Part of the deployment will create a shell script and execute it.  When the command executes, the first line works fine.  It's a simple 'cat file.txt >> /etc/httpd/file.conf' command.

The second line, I need to search for a string of text and place it within the file and it never runs successfully.  I can run the script manually as root with no issues.  Here is file:

```
#! /bin/bash
if ! grep -q 'Clickjacking' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf ;
then
    cat /home/ec2-user/httpd-update.conf >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
fi

# check if wsgi mod exists and insert into wsgi.conf if necessary
if ! grep -q 'TRACE|TRACK' /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf;
then
  sed -i -e '/WSGIProcessGroup wsgi/r /home/ec2-user/wsgi-update.conf' /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf
fi
sudo service httpd reload
```

Does anyone know why the `sed` command is not working in the shell script when Beanstalk deploys?

Comment: can you clarify the question? is the `sed` command executed but doesn't work or the entire script doesn't execute? also, is this file a `.config` file?

Comment: Beanstalk executes the shell script and the first part runs.  The sed command also runs but does not execute because the file did not get modified.  I can then take the script that was written on the server and run it manually, and the sed command will work whether I run as ec2-user with sudo or as root.

Comment: Can it be that you are running this script before the file is put in place or being replaced by the one being put there during deployment? Try running it as a container command.

Comment: I thought about that, but my beanstalk creates 2 files.  The script will then do 2 actions and only one of them is being performed.  The 2nd one, the file gets touched.  I evened tried having the script remove the file and download one I uploaded to S3 and didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

So I didn't realize our company had AWS support plan and contacted them.  The file I was trying to modify is also staged in beanstalk.  So while technically my file was getting updated, Beanstalk was then pushing their staged file into production.  You can run this command on the beanstalk instance:

```
[root@ip-10-0-90-168 ~]# /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container | python -mjson.tool
{
    "app_base_dir": "/opt/python/current",
    "app_deploy_dir": "/opt/python/current/app",
    "app_staging_base": "/opt/python/ondeck",
    "app_staging_dir": "/opt/python/ondeck/app",
    "app_user": "wsgi",
    "app_virtual_env": "/opt/python/run/venv",
    "base_path_dirs": "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin",
    "bundle_dir": "/opt/python/bundle",
    "env_deploy_config": "/opt/python/current/env",
    "env_staging_config": "/opt/python/ondeck/env",
    "instance_port": "80",
    "python_version": "2.7",
    "source_bundle": "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle",
    "wsgi_deploy_config": "/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf",
    "wsgi_staging_config": "/opt/python/ondeck/wsgi.conf"
}
```

And the file I was trying to update is the last one.  I need to run my command against that file and Amazon will then push that.